# Sample of data frame: second column no duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, sample

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:15, each = 3),
                   person = rep(c("Male 1", "Male 2", "Female 1", "Male 3", "Female 2 "), each =3),
                   group  = rep(letters[1:3]))
```

I would like to get a sample of the data frame by filtering based on two conditions: id and person but person cannot be duplicated. The outcome should look like this:

```
  id   person group
1  1   Male 1     a
2  1   Male 1     b
3  1   Male 1     c
4  7   Male 2     a
5  7   Male 2     b
6  7   Male 2     c
7 13 Female 1     a
8 13 Female 1     b
9 13 Female 1     c
```

but not like this, because here person is duplicated (id =2 / person = Male 2 and id = 7 / Male 2)

```
  id    person group
1  2    Male 2     a
2  2    Male 2     b
3  2    Male 2     c
4  7    Male 2     a
5  7    Male 2     b
6  7    Male 2     c
7 10 Female 2      a
8 10 Female 2      b
9 10 Female 2      c
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here I sampled 1 id for each person.

#### --data

```
data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:15, each = 3),
                   person = rep(c("Male 1", "Male 2", "Female 1", "Male 3", "Female 2 "), each =3),
                   group  = rep(letters[1:3]))

library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  inner_join(
    data %>% 
      select(id,person) %>% 
      distinct() %>% 
      group_by(person) %>% 
      sample_n(1)
  )
```

#### --output

```
Joining, by = c("id", "person")
   id    person group
1   1    Male 1     a
2   1    Male 1     b
3   1    Male 1     c
4   2    Male 2     a
5   2    Male 2     b
6   2    Male 2     c
7   4    Male 3     a
8   4    Male 3     b
9   4    Male 3     c
10 10  Female 2     a
11 10  Female 2     b
12 10  Female 2     c
13 13  Female 1     a
14 13  Female 1     b
15 13  Female 1     c
```

Comment: It works in the way it doen't duplicate person, but it always selects a sample of 5. Maybe I have not specified my question.